# ListView com Hibernate 3 não popula

Tags: hibernate, javafx, java-8

Tenho a classe abaixo, o método listarGeneroTreeView(), captura os valores que tenho no banco. Entretanto, não estou conseguindo exibir estes dados na treeview.
Sei apenas que funciona por uma mensagem que inseri para saber se estava certo.

public class RootLayoutController implements Initializable{

```
@FXML
private TextField txtPesquisa = new TextField();
@FXML
private Label lblStatus = new Label();
@FXML
private ProgressBar pbProgressBar = new ProgressBar();
@FXML
private TreeView<String> tvGenero;
@FXML
private TableView<DiscoTabela> tbvDiscos = new TableView();
@FXML
private TableColumn<DiscoTabela, Integer> clId;
@FXML
private TableColumn<DiscoTabela, String> clArtista;
@FXML
private TableColumn<DiscoTabela, String> clAlbum;
@FXML
private TableColumn<DiscoTabela, String> clAno_Gravado;
@FXML
private TableColumn<DiscoTabela, String> clGenero;
@FXML
private Button btnPesquisar = new Button();
@FXML
private Button btnDeletar = new Button();
@FXML
private Button btnEditar = new Button();
@FXML
private Button btnNovo = new Button();
@FXML
private Button btnNovo_Genero = new Button();
@FXML
private Button btnEditar_Genero = new Button();
@FXML
private Button btnDeletar_Genero = new Button();

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());


//Parametros para a clase disco
private DiscoDao discoDao = new DiscoDao();
private List<Disco> discoList = discoDao.listDisco();
private ObservableList<DiscoTabela> listDiscoTabela = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

//Parametros para a classe genero
private GeneroDao generoDao = new GeneroDao();
private List<Genero> generoList = generoDao.listGenero();
private ObservableList<String> listGeneroTabela = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

//Parametros para TreeView
private Node rootIcon = null;
private String T;
private TreeItem<String> rootNode = new TreeItem<String> ("Generos");


public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resourcebundle){
    //iniciaTreeView();
    listarGeneroTreeView();
    listarDiscos();
}  


@FXML
public void novo(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

    Disco tempDisco = new Disco();
    //Disco criteria = discoList.listIterator().next();
    //int nextID = criteria.getId();    

    if(showAddDialog(tempDisco)){
        discoList = discoDao.listDisco();
        listarDiscos();

    }

}

@FXML 
public void novoGenero(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

    Genero tempGenero = new Genero();
    //int crit = generoList.listIterator().next().getID();
    //int nextID = crit;

    if(showAddGeneroDialog(tempGenero)){
        logger.log(Level.ALL,"");
        generoList = generoDao.listGenero();
        listarGeneroTreeView();
    }
}

@FXML
public void editar(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

    DiscoTabela disco = tbvDiscos.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    int id = disco.getID();
    String artista = disco.getArtista();
    String album = disco.getDisco();
    String anoGravado = disco.getAnoGravado();
    String genero = disco.getGenero();


    if(showEditDialog(id, artista, album, anoGravado, genero)){
        discoList = discoDao.listDisco();
        listarDiscos();
    }

}

@FXML
private void editaGenero(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

}

@FXML
public void deletar(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    DiscoTabela disco = tbvDiscos.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    int id = disco.getID();

    listDiscoTabela.remove(disco);
    discoDao.delete(id);

    discoList = discoDao.listDisco();

    listarDiscos();     
}

@FXML
private void deletaGenero(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{        


}


@FXML
public void pesquisar(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{



}

private boolean showAddGeneroDialog(Genero genero) {
    try{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(this.getClass().getResource("/fxml/AdicionaGenero.fxml"));
        BorderPane addGenero = (BorderPane) loader.load();

        Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
        dialogStage.setTitle("Nova Genero");
        dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        dialogStage.initOwner(null);

        Scene cene = new Scene(addGenero);
        dialogStage.setScene(cene);

        //Define a pessoa no Controller
        AdicionaGeneroController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setDialogStage(dialogStage);
        controller.setGenero(genero);

        dialogStage.showAndWait();

        return controller.isOkClicked();
    }catch (IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean showAddDialog(Disco disco){
    try{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(this.getClass().getResource("/fxml/Adiciona.fxml"));
        BorderPane addLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

        Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
        dialogStage.setTitle("Nova entrada");
        dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        dialogStage.initOwner(null); 

        Scene cene = new Scene(addLayout);
        dialogStage.setScene(cene);

        //Define a pessoa no Controller
        AdicionaController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setDialogStage(dialogStage);
        controller.setDisco(disco);

        dialogStage.showAndWait();

        return controller.isOkClicked();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean showEditDialog(int id, String artista, String album, String anoGravado, String genero){
    try{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(this.getClass().getResource("/fxml/Edita.fxml"));
        BorderPane editLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

        Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
        dialogStage.setTitle("Editar Artista");
        dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        dialogStage.initOwner(null);

        Scene cene = new Scene(editLayout);
        dialogStage.setScene(cene);         

        EditaController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setDialogStage(dialogStage);
        controller.setDisco(id, artista, album, anoGravado, genero);

        dialogStage.showAndWait();

        return controller.isOkClicked();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public void listarDiscos(){
    if(!listDiscoTabela.isEmpty()){
        listDiscoTabela.clear();
        System.out.print("Limpou tabela");
    }

    for(Disco disco: discoList){

        try {
            DiscoTabela d = new DiscoTabela(disco.getId(), disco.getArtista(), disco.getDisco(), disco.getAnoGravado(), disco.getGenero());
            listDiscoTabela.add(d);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    clId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<DiscoTabela, Integer>("id"));
    clAlbum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<DiscoTabela, String>("disco"));
    clArtista.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<DiscoTabela, String>("artista"));
    clAno_Gravado.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<DiscoTabela, String>("anoGravado"));
    clGenero.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<DiscoTabela, String>("genero"));

    tbvDiscos.setItems(listDiscoTabela);
}


public void listarGeneroTreeView(){

    rootNode.setExpanded(true);

    if(!listGeneroTabela.isEmpty()){
        listGeneroTabela.clear();
        System.out.print("Limpou tabela GeneroTabela");
    }

    for(Genero genero: generoList){         
        try{
            GeneroTabela g = new GeneroTabela(genero.getID(), genero.getGenero());
            listGeneroTabela.add(g.getGenero());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    for(String genero: listGeneroTabela){
        TreeItem<String> generoLeaf = new TreeItem<>(genero, insertIcon(genero, rootIcon));
        rootNode.getChildren().add(generoLeaf);
    }
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setContentText(rootNode.getChildren().toString());
    alert.showAndWait();

    tvGenero = new TreeView<String>(rootNode);
    tvGenero.setShowRoot(true);
    tvGenero.setEditable(false);

}

private Node insertIcon(String T, Node rootIcon){

    String imagePath = "/icones/music folders/"+T+"/PNG/"+T+" 1.png";
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);

    rootIcon = new ImageView(
                new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imagePath)));

    alert.setGraphic(rootIcon);
    alert.showAndWait();

    return rootIcon;
}

private void showGeneroDetails(Genero genero){
    if(genero != null){

    }
}
```

}